# Is there a way to update the first document in a MongoDB collection given a query and a sort option using the "update" function?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like to use the `update` function in MongoDB to update the first document in a collection given a `query` and a `sort` (or `orderBy`) configuration.

I know the solution with [`findAndModify`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/):

```
db.col.findAndModify(query, sort, updates)
```

Can you do the same using the `update` function?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the `findAndModify`?

Comment: @Michael9 because I want to find out if the same can be achieved with `update` :) And of course I use it since I know no alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** you cannot use `sort` with [`update`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db-collection-update.) but if you do not specify `multi` option in your update only the first document that meet the **query** criteria will be updated.
There is no guarantee for the ordering of documents on disk unless your are using [Capped collections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/#capped-collections).

Comment: What does "first" mean?

Comment: But is there any implicit order? (place on disc, main index `_id`). For me it is important to update the first based on `_id`. And that is why I ask if I can rely on update for that. My practical experience shows me that also the default `_id` index is not considered for normal `update`

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of [UpdateOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#mongodb-method-db.collection.updateOne) Specify an empty document { } as filter to update the first document returned in the collection.